# Read HTML code from iframe using Webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, iframe, browser

How to read IFRAME html code using WebBrowser?

I have site with iframe, and after few clicks new URL opens inside this IFRAME with some portion of HTML CODE. Is there a possiblity to read this?. When I am trying to Navigate() to this URL, I am redirected to main page of this site (it is not possible to open this link twice).

```
Uri IFRAME_URL = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Url;
```

Maybe there is something similar to:

```
Uri IFRAME_URL = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].  ... DOCUMENTTEXT;
```

Comment: @Kiquenet see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013498/webbrowser-iframe-access-causing-unauthorized-access/20494120#20494120

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.InnerText;
```

Comment: string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.InnerText;

Comment: I used this and displayed content. I received URL of iframe ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry I meant "content" as variable. Instead of HTML code (source) I received URL of my iframe. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can also acquire various items via mshtml types:

Set a reference to the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" under COM references.

Set your using statement:

```
using mshtml;
```

Then tap into the mshtml API to snatch the source:

```
HTMLFrameBase frame = yourWebBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById( "yourFrameId" ).DomElement as HTMLFrameBase;
```

If "frame" isn't null after that line, it has a lot of items hanging off it for your use.

Comment: That's because of constraints restricting access between frames to circumvent cross-site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 1):

try:

string content = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.Body.InnerText

Answer (score 0):

A WebBrowser Control window can contain more that one iframe and .net supports frame collection so why not use something like this:

```
// Setup a string variable...
string html = string.Empty;

// webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames gets a collection of iframes contained in the current document...
// HTMLWindow is the iterator for the Collection...
foreach (HtmlWindow frame in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames)
{
html += frame.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
}
```

This way, maybe with a little adjustment you can get all you need from the iframe containers you need.